# Is there a specific and correct way to do single argument ternary operators?

Tags: javascript, ternary

I have a boolean constant that I use to determine whether I do an action. I'm quite fond of ternary operators because they look clean in most scenarios.

In my case, the action should be done if the constant is true and nothing should happen if the constant is false.

To me, I would handle it like this

```
BOOLEAN_CONSTANT ? doAction() : false;
```

but I'm unsure about whether this is "correct".

Is there a documented and/or recommended way to use the ternary operator with 1 argument?

If there isn't, i'll just use an if statement, but they take up more lines (unless you use a single line if which isn't part of the coding paradigm I follow).

---

It seems as if this question provokes opinionated responses down to the preferred coding style of a person. I follow a certain style that suits what I do, if you follow a different one that's completely okay.

I considered closing this thread, but I'll leave it to a moderator since I can't judge whether its existence would be classified as useful by SO guidelines.

Comment: So why are you not using an if statement? `if (BOOLEAN_CONSTANT) doAction();`

Comment: Why not do `BOOLEAN_CONSTANT && doAction();`

Comment: @epascarello It's just a case of clean code, and using too many if statements isn't fitting for the paradigm I choose.

Comment: @AndrewParks that is perfect, I didn't realise that was possible. If you add it as an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Well "clean code" is not ternary operations using incorrectly in a lot of people's viewpoint. :)

Comment: @epascarello hence why I asked the question

Comment: Ternaries are intended to be used as *expressions*, not statements. So you need a value for both cases.

Comment: I personally, find `if (SOME_CONSTANT) { doAction(); }` much cleaner than "abusing" the ternary operator or `SOME_CONSTANT && doAction()`

Comment: @derpirscher what is the issue with `SOMECONSTANT && doAction()`?

Comment: Some people don't like to use `&&` because it's an idiom people may not understand. Then again, Javascript is quite rich in idioms

Comment: @JoeMoore It's an expression, not a statement ... Same as the ternary operator.

Comment: @derpirscher but `doAction()` without any condition is also an expression, not a statement :)

Comment: I never understood those who downvote a question because they disagree with answers left that have nothing to do with the question itself. I understand why if you downvote to flag that the question may provoke opinionated answers, but since there is 1 close vote and 2 downvotes that cannot be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `&&` to evaluate the second expression only if the first expression is truthy:

`BOOLEAN_CONSTANT && doAction();`

Comment: As @derpirscher et al pointed out above, you can also use an if statement. My question was suited to those of us who follow paradigms that prefer smaller code, less brackets etc. Whether this suits you or not is completely your decision.